# Adding columns to dataset with table adapter c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, sql-update

I am having trouble updating the database from a dataset. The data is inserted into the datatable in the dataset correctly and I can see it in a datagridview, but when I look at the database the columns have not been added

This is my code below:

```
TimeSpan timeDif = dateToSet.Subtract(dateInTable);
int timeDifference = (int)timeDif.Days;

for (int i = 0; i < timeDifference; i++)
{
      DataColumn columnToAdd = new DataColumn(dateInTable.AddDays(i + 1).ToShortDateString());
      Program.pDiResourcesDataSet.WorkingProjects.Columns.Add(columnToAdd);
      Program.WorkingProjectsA.Update(Program.pDiResourcesDataSet.WorkingProjects);
}

Program.pDiResourcesDataSet.AcceptChanges();
Program.WorkingProjectsA.Update(Program.pDiResourcesDataSet);
```

Comment: You only add columns. There is no row being changed. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah, only wanting to add columns

Comment: The dataadapter doesn't generate DDL statements so the adapter will do nothing...

Comment: so i'll have to use SQL then

Comment: If that is really what you need, yes. I don't understand why you don't add rows to an existing table as that is a typical usecase but if you think that is the way to go, write the sql to add columns to your table.

Answer (score 0):

As rene said, you cannot add columns with dataadapter, rather use separate DDL statement to carry out the DDL operations, and use dataadapter to manipulate the records